# localStorage.removeItem(key); issue (even with correct key nothing changes on refresh)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following localStorage item set as follows :

```
localStorage.setItem("diary1536771000001", item);
```

yet when trying to remove item using the above key and the code :

```
localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000001');
```

the item is still present after refresh.

The task in hand is to be able to remove (delete) a diary entry that stays deleted upon refresh of the browser. Yet everything I've tried takes me back to the original page, complete with full diary entries. I've tried refreshing cache in chrome after code edits (I'm working on a university server which can be buggy sometimes) but still no luck. I've trawled across a few posts but except for telling me how to remove an item, I've come up empty handed.

Is there something I'm missing within my code that would keep the diary entry from reappearing upon next refresh?

I'm relatively new to this so apologies for anything i may have missed or syntax issues.

```
// Create and store demonstration data
  function createDemoItems() {

   var item;



item = makeItem(
      "text",
    "day 1."
    );
    localStorage.setItem("diary1536771000001", item);



item = makeItem(
      "text",
    "day 2."
    );
    localStorage.setItem("diary1536771000002", item);



 // Remove the item from local storage by key

    localStorage.removeItem("diary1536771000001");

}
```

Comment: Code works fine for me; after running it, I see only the 2nd item in localStorage. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c5x9gk6r/

Comment: The issue you are facing is not present in the snippet you have included. You will have to post more code if you want this answered.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're using a function that both adds and deletes the item you will never see it happen.

Also, localStorage is a key/value database which means you can only store a key and value, not a key with 2 different values like in your case.

If you open up your console and write

```
localStorage.setItem('diary1536771000001', 'text');
```

And then open up your inspector (in my case Google Chrome) and then go to the tab "Application", you will see under "Local Storage" that they key/value pair has been added.

If you then switch back to the console and write

```
localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000001');
```

And then check the Application tab again, you will see that it was removed.

Comment: I do think the OP is using two unique keys associated with two different values. One is `diary1536771000001` and the other is `diary1536771000002` (i.e., a 2 at the end instead of a 1). At first glance I thought they were the same key though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i used the console as suggested and as you said within local storage was the diary1536771000001, however when trying the second console command nothing changed within local storage. am i missing a step somewhere?

Comment: AndroidNoobie, that is correct, a total of 4 diary entries are present, all similar bar the last number. just to point out, other than the code trying to remove the item which is me everything else is done via the university